# implementing one method from another in Objective-C, combining plugins

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, methods, plugins

I'm trying to combine two plugins written in Objective-C. I have Plugin1 and Plugin2 which execute fine enough independently. I'm trying to add the Plugin2.m code to my Plugin1 Classes folder and execute both at the same time.

When I do this, Plugin1.m seems to execute first, I guess because it has IBAction calls and Plugin2.m doesn't? This is fine, but I'd like to run Plugin2.m within a function in Code1.m. So In the code below, when the IBAction call in Plugin1 is initiated I would like it to do what Plugin2 normally does and then continue with Plugin1 methods.

Plugin1.h:

```
#import Plugin2.h

@interface Plugin1: NSWindowController {
...
}
+(void) Plugin2;
@end
```

Plugin1.m:

```
#import "Plugin1.h"
#import "Plugin2.h"

@implementation Plugin1

-(id) loadPlugin1
{
...
}

-(IBAction) computeStuff:(id)sender
{
[self Plugin2];
//Plugin2* testRun = [Plugin2 alloc] init];

...do other stuff
}

@end
```

Plugin2.h

```
@interface Plugin2 : PluginFilter {
...
}
@end
```

Plugin2.m:

```
#import Plugin2.h

@implementation Plugin2

-(void) initPlugin
{
...
}

@end
```

Unfortunately I can't troubleshoot this from within Xcode, I have to install and test the plugin on my program to test. But when I keep an eye on Console and try the above I get "-[Plugin1 Plugin2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7....

Answer (score 0):

in your plugin1 interface you defined

```
+(void)plugin2;
```

but implemented no method

```
+(void)plugin2 {

}
```

when you invoke `+` method you need to tell which class you call the method from because **self** refers to an object and not the class.

```
[self.class plugin2];
// OR
[Plugin1 plugin2];
```

Hints: try to follow naming conventions in objective-c.
This will help you distinguish if a definition is a `-method:` or `Class`

Consider reading about `delegate` design patterns and the use of `<Protocols>`

Also define special `-initPlugin` in your Plugin2 implementation and use a return type. Otherwise you initialise nothing.

```
-(instancetype)initPlugin;
```